# Get the tail of an array

Tags: c#

What is the simplest way to get the tail of an array in C# - ie. all but the first element.

Comment: There are multiple interpretations of your question: do you want a copy of the array elements? Do you want to iterate over the original array, skipping the first?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var myArray = GetSomeArray();
myArray = myArray.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Note that I would avoid calling .ToArray() as much as possible and stick to using `IEnumerable<T>` instead in .Net.

Comment: But... if you are going to call ToArray as above, it's probably much more efficient to use Array.Copy because I don't believe ToArray will know enough about its input to initialize the array at length-1.

Comment: @Josh: That's true (I assume `ToArray` would work by building up a `List` internally and calling `ToArray` on *that*), but it would be better to simply not call `ToArray` at all, if you didn't have to.

Comment: What's wrong with `ToArray` calls? Performance ⚡ concerns?

Comment: @CodeFinity Yes. It's usually just adding more code to make things less efficient and wasteful.

Answer (score 6):

[Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx):

```
var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var array2 = new int[array1.Length - 1];
Array.Copy(array1, 1, array2, 0, array2.Length);

// array2 now contains {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

**Edit**: Joel Coehoorn's answer is better, because it means you can avoid using arrays altogether!

Answer (score 1):

Lol call me old school, but hey its valid!

```
for(int i = 1; i<array.length;i++)
{
   array2[i-1]=array[i];
}
```

:P

or you could yield them if they were in a method and you just need to call them, it just depend on what you want to do with the tail.

```
for(int i = 1; i<array.length;i++)
{
   yield return array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer codeka's answer, since it's very straightforward, and probably the most efficient way of doing things.  However, as you can see, it's not the simplest to implement when you need it.

I've got something very similar, as an extension method, so you can call SubArray, and it will behave like Substring on a string.

Something like:

```
public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
{
  // various null, empty, out of range checks here

  T[] returnArray = new T[length];
  Array.Copy(array, startIndex, returnArray, 0, length);
  return returnArray;
}

var array1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var arrays2 = array1.SubArray(2, 3);
```

You could implement a few other overloads, such as:

```
public static T[] SubArray<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex)
{
  // null check here

  return SubArray(array, startIndex, array.Length - startIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

var array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var tail = array.Reverse ().Take (array.Length - 1).Reverse ();
```